# Create new sheet and copy a row via macro

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using google forms with the responses automatically going into a google sheet. Every time someone submits a form it fills in a new row. When i run a macro I would like it to open a new blank sheet and paste the latest row into it

I can get it to create a new sheet when i run the macro but it doesn't copy anything.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Insert new sheet on every form submit and post submitted row

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.insertSheet(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss:S"));
  sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, e.values.length).setValues([e.values]);
}
```

Need to create an installable onFormSubmit trigger for the above function.

[onFormSubmit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Thank you , it comes up with this 9:59:54 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined
autoFillGoogleDocFromForm @ Code.gs:2

Comment: It cannot be run from the script editor it requires an onFormSubmit trigger